# Tracking speed with kinect and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, kinect

I need to track the speed of a kick. I programmed this code, but when I run the program even when I move my Right Foot very fast, the speed does not change too much.
what is wrong?
Is there a different approache?

```
if (bandera == true)
{
X1 = skeleton.Joints[JointType.FootRight].Position.X;
Y1 = skeleton.Joints[JointType.FootRight].Position.Y;
Z1 = skeleton.Joints[JointType.FootRight].Position.Z;
}
if (bandera == false)
{  
X2 = skeleton.Joints[JointType.FootRight].Position.X;
Y2 = skeleton.Joints[JointType.FootRight].Position.Y;
Z2 = skeleton.Joints[JointType.FootRight].Position.Z;
}
bandera = !bandera;

float d= (((X1 - X2) * (X1 - X2)) + ((Y1 - Y2) * (Y1 - Y2)) + ((Z1 - Z2 * (Z1 - Z2))));
double distance = System.Math.Sqrt(d);
double speed= 30 * distance;
Console.WriteLine(speed);
```

As you know: Speed= distance/time
And I understand there are 30 FPS per second, so time = 1/30
So speed equals distance divided by (1/30) is equal 30 * distance

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html

Answer (score 0):

Well ... because you're using the same points ... so when you're subtracting, it's all 0's ...

```
X1 = skeleton.Joints[JointType.FootRight].Position.X;
...
X2 = skeleton.Joints[JointType.FootRight].Position.X;
...
```

same point, so `x1=x2`, `x1-x2=0`, and everything goes pear shape from there...

---

As per your update:

1. I hope that is in a loop, otherwise, your flag (bandera) won't do much. I hope you also realize that the first time through the loop, some of your `X` and `Y` won't be initialized (because it'll only go through one of the cases).
2. now, `d=t*s`, so your distance calculation is completely correct.

If you chuck some debug output after initializing your variables, and calculations, what do you get ?

Comment: This code is run (I assume) on the Kinect's frame event, which runs, as she stated, 30 times per second. So, on every other frame, X1 and X2 are updated to different values.

Answer (score 0):

You messed up the distance formula. Take great care when placing parentesis. It should look like so

```
float d = (X1 - X2) * (X1 - X2) + (Y1 - Y2) * (Y1 - Y2) + (Z1 - Z2) * (Z1 - Z2);
```

Also there is no need to compare a bool value to `true`. You can also move out the distance calculation to its own method to make things clearer and avoid misstakes that take time to find. I suggest something like this:

```
double distance(Joint a, Joint b)
{
    float d2 = (b.X - a.X) * (b.X - a.X) + (b.Y - a.Y) * (b.Y - a.Y) + (b.Z - a.Z) * (b.Z - a.Z);
    return System.Math.Sqrt(d2)
}

...

if (bandera)
{
    a = skeleton.Joints[JointType.FootRight];
}
else
{  
    b = skeleton.Joints[JointType.FootRight];
}
bandera = !bandera;

double speed = 30 * distance(a, b);
Console.WriteLine(speed);
```

Your speed calculation is very prone to fluctuation, so averaging over say 10 frames would probably also help.

Answer (score 0):

The only mistake I see in your code is that you're missing parenthesis on the distance calculation: (Z1 - Z2) must go between parenthesis, or else the order of the operations is incorrect. Everything else should work fine. As vidstige stated, the speed will vary when the kick is in progress, so for your stated purpose I would recommend simply keeping the greatest value.

Saludos!!